# Magento 2.4 PayPal Express Checkout In-Context : error Unauthorized. Missing a required scope

Tags: paypal, magento2.4

Trying to test in-context payment on sandbox

Using bundled extension

[image]

On checkout when trying to pay seeing error

```
Request URL:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/graphql?GetCheckoutDetails
Request method:POST
```

```json
{"error":"Unauthorized.  Missing a required scope.  Retry your request with a valid access token or session token.","correlation_id":"39a10eb397597",...
```

[image]

Any ideas? One-click payment from product page and basket doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched browser and seems okay. Broken in Firefox works in chrome. I can only assume something browser plug-in related, session based or related to local storage stopped this from working. Nothing in payment.log beyond acknowledgment of a successful registration of transaction. Credentials are okay. Not using in-context mode works. Doesn't appear to be a PayPal or account related issue such as permission to perform a certain action or call.

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/325882/57334 thanks @Dominic Xigen